# Which one is correct, "Taking day off Monday" or "taking day off on Monday"?

Tags: sentence-choice

I am bit confused which of these sentences is correct when I write an email for leave.

Which one is correct?

> Taking day off Monday

or

> Taking day off **on** Monday

Comment: I am taking a day off on Monday

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither is correct. You can say "I'm taking Monday off."  That is the simplest expression.

You can also say "I'm taking a day off on Monday."  or "I'm taking the day off on Monday". If you use "the", it suggests that you are thinking only of Monday. If you use "a", it might mean that you have multiple days off available, and you are using just one of them.